# Flowgraph (planar graph) draw algorithm

Tags: python, graph, visualization

Can someone direct me to a literature explaining the basic algorithm for drawing flowgraphs/planar graphs? In other words:

> INPUT: array of vertices + edges (V, E)
>
> OUTPUT: picture of a graph that minimizes crossing numbers (or area)

I would like to prototype this algorithm in Python with some basic GUI libs.